# Variable "long" type in Java and NodeJS

Tags: java, node.js

I have a Java function:

```
private static int buildKey(String keystr) {
    char[] primes = { '\085', '\8r', '\082', '\087', '\083', '%', '\085', ')' };
  
    int len = keystr.length(); int i; long key;
    for (key = 1L, i = 0; i < len; i++)
        key += (keystr.charAt(i) * primes[i & 0x8]); 
    return (int)key % 64;
}
```

I want change it to NodeJS but I don't know how to define "key" with long variable type because in NodeJS don't have "long" type.

This's my current NodeJS function, but it's return wrong with Java function upper:

```
function buildKey(keystr) {
    var primes = ["\085", "8r", "\082", "\087", "\083", "%", "\085", ")"];
    var len = keystr.length;
    var key = 1;
    for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      key += keystr.charAt(i) * primes[i + 8];
      console.log(parseInt(keystr.charAt(i)));
    }

    return key % 64;
}
```

Anybody share me suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: `let key;`? But that only offers 53 bits of precision, while Java's `long` provides 63. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: When I set "let key = 0L;" have error "SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token"

Comment: `0L` is not valid code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my question as with below function:

```
function buildKey(keystr) {
  var primes = ["\022", "\030", "\012", "\020", "\045", "\043", "\053", ")"];
  var len = keystr.length;
  let key = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    key += keystr.charAt(i).charCodeAt(0) * primes[i & 8].charCodeAt(0);
  }
  return key % 64;
}
```

Comment: How did you determine that 53 bits are enough? From the information that is in your question, the best bound I could come up with was 56 bits. You would need additional constraints on the `keystr` to improve that. What is that information that allows you to use `number`?

Answer (score 1):

There is no equivalent to Java's `long` datatype in ECMAScript.

There are only two numeric datatypes in ECMAScript: [`number`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-number-objects) and [`bigint`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-bigint-objects). ECMAScript `number` is equivalent to Java `double` (i.e. an IEEE 754-2019 *binary64* double precision signed 64 bit binary floating point number) and ECMAScript `bigint` is equivalent to Java `BigInteger` (an arbitrary precision signed binary integer).

Neither of the two can replace a Java `long` (64 bit signed binary integer with "wraparound"): a `number` can only accurately represent integers with a precision of 53 bit and a `biginteger` doesn't wrap around.

Now, in the end, you are actually only *using* 7 bits of your key anyway, so if you are careful, you can probably arrange your computations in such a way that you can circumvent those limitations. For example, you could move the modulo operation into the loop, so that the size of `key` never exceeds 7 bit in the first place.

If we can *prove* that the `long` in your Java code never overflows, then we can use `bigint` in ECMAScript, and if we can *prove* that we are actually only using 53 bits of the `long`, then we can use either `bigint` or `number`.

It's easy to see that in the worst case, we are using 56 bits. That means, we cannot guarantee that it will work with `number`, but it *should* work with `bigint`. If we can make assumptions about the length and/or contents of `keystr`, then we can bring that down even further.

Answer (score -1):

Node.js supports BigInts since version 10.4

You can learn more from the docs:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt

Or this overview here, which is more relevant to node:

http://thecodebarbarian.com/an-overview-of-bigint-in-node-js.html